# Show that $\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)e^{-(ny)^2}dy$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $\Lambda_n(f)(x) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)e^{-(ny)^2}dy.$
Show that $\Lambda_n(f)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for all n, given that : 
    $$ \frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(ny)^2}dy =1$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I am not understand i fully understand the notation. Can one assume $f(x-y)$ can be evaluated as some function $f(y) + K, K\in \mathbb{R}$, so that one can look at the integral:
    $$ \frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(f(y) +K)e^{-(ny)^2}dy $$
After looking at this for quite some time, it does not seem like simply looking at $\epsilon - \delta$ on $\Lambda(f)(x)$ gets me very far without some usful simplification. 
If anybody has a suggestion to a usful theorem or result that can get me started, I would be very greatful.

Comment: $f(x-y)$ is not some function $f(y)+K$.

Comment: The integral need not be finite. You need a further condition on $f.$

Comment: I know $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$